# Fuzzy Finder behaving abnormally

Tags: files, search

I started using [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) recently. But the output it's showing is quite strange. I am using FZF version 0.21.1 and Ubuntu 17.10

[image: FZF Output].

It should return the filenames clearly.

Comment: I know. But my laptop has some issues with the other distros. In the output, the prefix "[1;35m" is extra and the suffix "[0m" too.

Comment: The prefix and suffix appear to be ANSI escape sequences for coloring the output - either they are being emitted incorrectly or your terminal is not able to process them

Comment: @steeldriver I am using tmux and zsh. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that putting this line in my .zshrc file solves the issue.

```
export TERM="xterm-256color"
```

Thanks for the idea [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)